# scrollTo across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery `scrollTo` working on a single page of a website, by calling each elements' `id` which activates the scroll.

What I would like to do is include elements on another page, which when the the link in the menu is clicked, loads the new page and scrolls to the correct element.

For example if my contact section is at the bottom of "page 1" but I am on "page 2". I would like to be able to click contact in the menu and it load "page 1" and then scroll to the contact section at the bottom.

The current script and code I am using are the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToByScroll(id){
        $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top },'slow');
    }
    var hash = window.location.hash;

    setTimeout(function(){
        goToByScroll(hash);
    }, 300);
</script>
```

The navigation link is:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="goToByScroll('contact')">contact</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to do this.

1: You can use ajax to load the other page, but this means that any javascript in the page itself won't run, unless you use eval(bad option). A better way is to trigger a function that fixes all javascript based on the page you are loading.

2: Pass a parameter via the url, which tells that a scrollto should be trigger to a certain ID. But this will clutter your url.

Reply on the comment:
I've created a proof of concept here:
http://stackoverflow.stijnd.be/scrollto-fix/?tar=Scrollto3

The javascript checks the url for a query-string and parses it: this is the jquery-code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_url = document.URL;

    var qry_start = current_url.indexOf('?');
    var qry_str_values = new Array();

    if(qry_start)
    {
        var qry_str = current_url.substring((qry_start+1));//omit ?
        var qry_str_array = qry_str.split('&');

        for(var i=0; i < qry_str_array.length; i++)
        {
            var tmp_pair = qry_str_array[i].split('=');
            qry_str_values[tmp_pair[0]] = tmp_pair[1];
        }

        if(typeof qry_str_values['tar'] != 'undefined')
        {
            alert('The page should scroll to: #'+qry_str_values['tar']);
            $.scrollTo('#'+qry_str_values['tar'], 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Couldn't find the tar-key in the querystring!");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this gets you on your way

Comment: Could you provide some code on how you would achieve point 2 please. I have tried something along the same lines but couldn't quite get it to work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do I keep the links in my menu the same?